# Obtaining the flavor used to create a virtual device

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the stanza supplementalCreateObjectOptions with flavorKeyName to create a virtual guest. I am using the SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests to obtain information about an existing virtual guest. How do I obtain the flavor KeyName used to create this virtual guest? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used the mask billingItem.orderItem.preset and in the json payload the flavor the VSI was created with is in {billingItem}->{orderItem}->{preset}->{keyName}